# Why did I just now get the "Excavator" badge for an edit I made 3 years ago?

Tags: support, badges

I opened Stack Exchange today to find a pleasant notification:

> You've earned the "Excavator" badge (edited first post that was inactive for 6 months) for [this post](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/555/why-isnt-my-htc-hero-upgrading)

As you can see, I edited that post a full 3 years ago.

[The list of people that received that badge](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/badges/73/excavator) reveals that the badge wasn't something recently added (the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/59446/152101) agrees), and that there seemingly wasn't some massive influx of them awarded all at once, as you'd expect if there were some bug preventing me and some other people from getting our badges on time.

What gives?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A [bug was recently fixed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/278953) that prevented the badge from being awarded on posts where the owner had since been deleted.